# How can I animate a graphviz with javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, graphviz

is there some library javascript to animate (only move the nodes) a graph created with graphviz?

I want to show a svg (created with graphviz) into a browser, but I want to the nodes can move (with its edges) something like to the [dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/)

Thanks you

Comment: Is there anything you have done already? Some code sample or something like this? Ask on the [CHAT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for plugins advise.

Comment: Of course. This is my project https://github.com/goinnn/django-detect-cyclic but I want animate any svg created with graphviz.

Comment: Why -4?? This is excessive... almost bullying. For me this is a very good question. I don't understand why negative vote? Please tell me a reason

Comment: Not sure, but I believe that is because your questio **looks like** a "Search this stuff for me?" or "How can I do 'it' like they did?"

Comment: Just try make your question more attractive. With more specification about your problem and code-sample. 4 lines sometimes are enough to explain all you need, sometimes isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking something like [this](https://github.com/goinnn/jquery.graphviz). I thought that somebody, sometime, would have needed it. But finally I have had to code it.

This plugin is not complete, but this is a first step